# Mysql 5.0.51 vs 5.1.66 perfomance issue

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have 2 mysql servers

Server A has mysql 5.0.51 - 8GB RAM Single Quad Core
Server B has mysql 5.1.66 - 64GB RAM - 2x Quad Core

Running the following query

```
 select FULLNAME ,(select COUNT(*) FROM ORDERS S, ACCOUNTS T WHERE S.CREATED BETWEEN  '2013-04-21 00:00' AND '2013-04-27 23:59'  AND S.ACCOUNT=T.ACCOUNT AND T.USERNAME=U.USERNAME AND T.CUSTOMERSTATUS = 'Donation'
     and T.TIMEST=
      (SELECT TC.TIMEST FROM  DETAILS A, ACCOUNTS TC WHERE S.ACCOUNT=A.ACCOUNT AND A.ACCOUNT = TC.ACCOUNT AND T.USERNAME=U.USERNAME AND T.CUSTOMERSTATUS = 'Donation' AND A.ANAL16 <> 'Cheque' order by TIMEST DESC LIMIT 1))
```

from USERS U

On server A it completes in 27 seconds

On server B it never finishes - I just terminated it now after sending data for 400 seconds.

Here is the configuration variables from server A

join_buffer_size               131072
 key_buffer_size                16777216
 myisam_sort_buffer_size        8388608
 net_buffer_length              16384
 preload_buffer_size            32768
 read_buffer_size               131072
 read_rnd_buffer_size           262144
 sort_buffer_size               2097144

and the same from server B

join_buffer_size         131072
 key_buffer_size          16777216
 myisam_sort_buffer_size  8388608
 net_buffer_length        16384
 preload_buffer_size      32768
 read_buffer_size         131072
 read_rnd_buffer_size     262144
 sort_buffer_size         2097144
 sql_buffer_result        OFF

I just can't figure out why it doesn't complete on the faster, much more powerful server.

I found a few posts online but they all mentioned it was an 'indexing' issue but I can't fathom out how its any different between the 2 machines, I took the dump this morning with all the indexes and it all re-imported fine.

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update with explain code**

Server A

```
  1  PRIMARY             U      ALL   NULL                           NULL        NULL     NULL                                      57  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
  3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  S      ALL   PRIMARY,ACCSTO0472             NULL        NULL     NULL                                    3948  Using where; Using temporary                  
  3  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  T      ref   PRIMARY,TELCOM0473             TELCOM0473  9        func                                       1  Using where                                   
  4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  TC     ref   PRIMARY,TELCOM0472             PRIMARY     98       tms42_gg.S.ACCOUNT                      2273  Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort  
  4  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  A      ref   PRIMARY,RCMANL0472,RCMANL0473  RCMANL0473  98       tms42_gg.S.ACCOUNT                         1  Using where; Using index                      
  2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  R      ALL   PRIMARY                        NULL        NULL     NULL                                     636  Using where; Using temporary                  
  2  DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  T      ref   PRIMARY,ACCSTO0122             ACCSTO0122  250      tms42_gg.R.ACCOUNT,tms42_gg.U.USERNAME     1  Using where
```

Server B

```
|  1 | PRIMARY            | U     | ALL   | NULL                                      | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                   |   57 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | S     | ALL   | PRIMARY,ACCSTO0472                        | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                   | 3948 | Using where; Using temporary                 |
|  3 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | T     | ref   | PRIMARY,TELCOM0473,TELCOM047J,TELCOM047JR | TELCOM0473 | 9       | func                                   |    1 | Using where                                  |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | TC    | index | PRIMARY,TELCOM0472,TELCOM047J,TELCOM047JR | TELCOM0473 | 9       | NULL                                   |    1 | Using where; Using temporary                 |
|  4 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | A     | ref   | PRIMARY,RCMANL0472,RCMANL0473             | RCMANL0473 | 98      | tms42_gg.S.ACCOUNT                     |    1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | R     | ALL   | PRIMARY                                   | NULL       | NULL    | NULL                                   |  636 | Using where; Using temporary                 |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | T     | ref   | PRIMARY,ACCSTO0122                        | ACCSTO0122 | 250     | tms42_gg.R.ACCOUNT,tms42_gg.U.USERNAME |    1 | Using where
```

**I set SESSION SQL_BUFFER_RESULT= ON before running the explain in both places - still the same results!**

Comment: do an `explain` of the query on both servers and look for differences. Note that your server configs ARE different - server B has `sql_buffer_result` set to OFF.

Comment: Kudos for the `ANAL16` column name, made me snicker.

Comment: Are your table types the same?

Comment: Tables types are all MyISAM - Will post explain output now

Comment: Might be worth running ANALYZE TABLE on each of the tables on each server before retrying the EXPLAINs.

Comment: Also it looks like you tables may be different on the 2 servers. Given that the possible indexes vary between the 2 explains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That SQL looks pretty inefficient with nested correlated queries.

Not sure I have understood quite what you are trying to do, but try recoding it something like this:-

```
SELECT U.FULLNAME , Sub2.RecCount
FROM USERS U
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select T.USERNAME, COUNT(*) AS RecCount
FROM ORDERS S
INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS T ON S.ACCOUNT = T.ACCOUNT 
INNER JOIN (SELECT A.ACCOUNT, MAX(TC.TIMEST) AS MaxTimeSt
      FROM  DETAILS A
      INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS TC ON A.ACCOUNT = TC.ACCOUNT
      WHERE A.ANAL16 != 'Cheque' 
      GROUP BY A.ACCOUNT) Sub1 ON S.ACCOUNT = Sub1.ACCOUNT AND T.TIMEST = Sub1.MaxTimeSt
WHERE S.CREATED BETWEEN  '2013-04-21 00:00' AND '2013-04-27 23:59'  
AND T.USERNAME = U.USERNAME 
AND T.CUSTOMERSTATUS = 'Donation' 
GROUP BY T.USERNAME) Sub2
ON Sub2.USERNAME = U.USERNAME
```

Not tested so please excuse any typos

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - the query is the first few columns in a report - the whole thing runs on server A in less than 30 seconds but on server B it doesn't finish. I pulled it apart and found that adding in the subquery caused it to fail which is what I posted here. Trying your idea to see if it makes it any more efficient

Comment: I suspect the indexes you have set up on each server are different, and / or you need to run analyze table on each of the tables on each server. In you original post MySQL has found different possible keys, and then chosen different keys. The above SQL is a suggestion to improve the performance (afraid I am not 100% sure of your tables so I can't be certain it is exactly waht you want. Generally having a sub query that accesses a field outside of that query (correlated sub query) will perform badly as it will be executed for each returned row of the outer query.

Comment: I changed the SQL to include the table it was counting in the orignal query. The old code on server A ran in 27 seconds. The new code on Server B now completes in 1.5 seconds so thanks for the suggestion!